# Отправка сообщений в timeline социальной страницы в Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-api

Доброго времени суток! Как отправить сообщение в  `timeline` социальной страницы в `Facebook` и позволяет ли это `Graph API`? Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У Facebook есть [Android API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) - по ссылке все подробно разжевано что как и куда
2. Graph API Facebook'а независима от его API Android и позволяет довольно просто постить в таймлайн - [пример тут](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) - остается только реализовать вызовы Graph API средствами Android API Facebook'а

Comment: спасибо,буду разбираться